# hudson2 project android build turn indefinitely

Tags: android, performance, continuous-integration, hudson

i configure a automatic build for continu integration for an android project, the problem the build turn all time, without interruption, i want to do that only after a commit.

Wa can see on the picture the build witch never stops

any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve the problem by adding:

0 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18 * * *

so the build can start at 8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,18  every day